# When should a question not be answered?

Tags: discussion

(It's hard for me to believe that this question has not been asked before, but I couldn't find a duplicate.)

I'm thinking specifically of a question like [this one](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/29377/prevalence-of-offshoring-in-the-information-security-industry).   Answers for this question will obviously be opinion based, although I think reasonable people can probably disagree on whether it's appropriate for this site, since we often allow questions that draw upon users' opinions rather than upon hard data if those questions are asked properly. The question is currently on hold, but several people disagree with its on hold status. Similar situations appear to arise pretty often.

For "gray area" questions like this, is it better to delay answering until a clear direction emerges on the question's appropriateness, or is it considered OK to answer and let these decisions be made later?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions

Comment: Similar, but not exactly the same.  I agree that there's nothing to be gained by answering questions that are obviously off-topic - my question is more about ones that fall into the gray area.

Comment: The big problem right now is that the post is a "poll". There's no problem to be solved. The post doesn't clearly define what the question is or what goal the asker is seeking. It's way too open ended and broad. With some editing, those things can all be fixed.

Comment: Don't answer this: Is the answer to this question "No"?

Comment: Only when there's _no conceivable way_ that another human being will benefit from the question being answered?  Otherwise I'd think that even an 'inappropriate' question is worth answering.

Comment: I'm with aroth, the more content the better.